# Is there an MP7 player or some means of converting it?

Tags: video, mp4, video-playback

I just got a video from a friend and he sent it in the file format of "mp7".

Does anyone know an MP7 player for Linux, Mac or PC or means of converting it to an MP4, preferably?

Comment: There is no such thing as MP7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All Patients Lie... As do file name extensions

Now, as far as i know there's no such thing as an MP7 - even the chinese knockoff players only go up to 5!.

On the other hand, you can probably ID the file using [Trid](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) on windows, or the file command on linux or alternately since its a media file, you can use [mediainfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) to identify it.

Once identified, it'll be much easier to work out what codecs you need to play it.

Comment: touché with the chinese player...

Comment: I've actually seen MP5 players at local dodgy crapgadget vendors. I've never seen MP6 or 7. T

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean ".mp4" . MP4 is a container file, and can have various codecs (types of encoded audio / video) in it. It usually refers to a file that is playable in Quicktime.

In any case, I would recommend [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/). VLC should be able to play just about any audio or video file you throw at it. It is also available for Windows, Mac and Linux.

Comment: I believe VLC doesn't look at the file's extension, but opens the file and analyzes it before playing.  Try installing VLC and dragging/dropping the file on its playlist window.

Answer (score 1):

I did find this Forum Post about a ["Mp7 file-type"](http://www.sevenforums.com/music-pictures-video/148677-mp7-file-format.html)

> I've just recently come across an .mp7 video file and when googling it, found some people saying that you should rename the .mp7 to either .avi or .mpg. Searching .mp7 here came up with no results so, I thought I'd post this to help anyone who comes across apparently a rare file type. 
>   Although renaming the file to .avi or .mpg still plays the video, it doesn't display a video thumbnail. So I renamed it instead to .mp4 and this displays the thumbnail and plays the video.

one of the answers states

> I think it is an ordinary mp4 file only renamed to mp7.
>   You might try renaming it to mp4. if it contains avc and aac it is most probably mp4.

beond that ... I have no idea